# If cell contains certain text put this text in a cell

Tags: excel

I have a dataset like this:

```
      A     B          C
1     A     A is this   
2     B     Z is this
3     C     D is this
4     D     A is this
5     E     K is this
```

If cell B1 contains A, B, C, D or E (so a value of column A) than I want to put A,B,C,D,or E in cell C1

I've tried to do this with the following formula for C1:

```
=IF(FIND("A";B1;1);"A";IF(FIND("B";B1;1");"B";IF(FIND("C";B1;1) ...
```

But since my column A contains 24 possible values it becomes a very long formula.

Can someone help me to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following formula in column C:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(FIND(A:A,B1)),0))
```

Enter it as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I only needed to changed the "," into ";"

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue (trying to categorize lines of data based on criteria contained in one cell).
It’s a really ugly formula, but it works:

=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".03",Q4,1)),(IF(ISERROR(FIND("F",Q4,1)),(IF(ISERROR(FIND(".50",Q4,1)),(IF(ISERROR(FIND(".25",Q4,1)),(IF(Q4>"A","other","Parts")),"Svc")),"Install")),"Frt")),"Mach")

The find function brings back either a match or an error (#VALUE), so the ISERROR had to be added each time there was a new search.

The best way to read the formula is starting at the far left, matching to the far right, and working your way inward (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6---- A6, A5, A4, A3, A2, A1)

It was impossible to find this in excel help, and difficult to find on the Web, so I wanted to share this incase others are having issue creating formulas to determine value based on if a cell conatins criteria.